# Does this sentence make sense? ( I feel comfortable like in the living room.)

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

I want to know if it is acceptable to a native speaker to say

> "I feel comfortable like in the living room."

Is there any problem in *I feel comfortable like in the living room.*?

Comment: What is the intended meaning of the sentence? It isn't obvious to me, which might indicate that it could be improved...

Comment: It's syntactically *valid*, but not something a native speaker would normally say. One idiomatic standard in this area is *I feel **at home** here*. Which you'll also encounter as the imperative *Make yourself at home* spoken to a guest (approximately equivalent to [mi-casa-su-casa](http://www.yourdictionary.com/mi-casa-su-casa) as appropriated into English from Spanish).

Comment: You need to supply more context with your questions. As things go, they're of low quality, so that most of the time we must guess what you want to say and guess what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dentist's office, but I feel comfortable, like in my living room.

I feel comfortable here, like I was in my living room.

I feel comfortable here, as though I were in my living room.

I feel as comfortable here as in my living room.

Your:

> I feel comfortable, like in the living room.

is implicitly comparing *something* with the way you feel in your living room. But you don't say what it is. So, absent context, one would understand it refer to the way you feel as you're speaking.

Comment: This is a dentist's office, but I feel comfortable, like in my living room. (the comma is necessary for the sentence above?)

Comment: Yes, the meaning of the sentence is something I intended. but, I want to know if it is OK to delete the comma in the sentence above you made.

Comment: The example sentence is a colloquial statement.  There is no need for a comma there, but neither is it a problem to put one there.  Punctuation is not part of grammar, strictly speaking. It is merely an aid to readers, and certain conventions have developed around it.